# How to add pagination to an XML feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using javascript to make XML to HTML. I have followed this guide:http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp

How do I add pagination to a XML feed?

Comment: Are you working in Rails (as evidenced by your username)? We need to know your target environment in order to have any chance of answering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the url you provided in your question, here is how you can paginate the data.

The html content:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="pagination"></div>
```

The Javascript code:

```
var page = 1, perPage = 4, content = document.getElementById('content'),
pagination = document.getElementById('pagination'), records;

function paganation(page)
{
    var nextMaxItem = perPage * page;
    var fromItem = (page - 1) * perPage;
    var maxPages = records.length / perPage;

    var xmlContent = "<table border='1'>";
    for (var i = fromItem; i < nextMaxItem; i++) {
        xmlContent += "<tr><td>";
        xmlContent += records[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        xmlContent += "</td><td>";
        xmlContent += records[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        xmlContent += "</td></tr>";
    }
    xmlContent += "</table>";
    content.innerHTML = xmlContent;

    var paginationContent = "";
    var previous = page - 1;
    if (page > 1) {
        paginationContent += '<a href="javascript:paganation('+previous+');">Back</a>';
    } else {
        paginationContent += "Back";
    }

    for (var j = 1; j < Math.ceil(maxPages); j++) {
        paginationContent += " ";
        paginationContent += '<a href="javascript:paganation('+j+');">'+j+'</a>';
        paginationContent += " ";
    }

    var next = page + 1;
    if (next <= maxPages) {
        paginationContent += '<a href="javascript:paganation('+next+');">Next</a>';
    } else {
        paginationContent += "Next";
    }
    pagination.innerHTML = paginationContent;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
paganation(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is the Ruby gem, [will_paginate](http://rubygems.org/gems/will_paginate) ([this page](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) explains the basics of using it).

If you're developing in Rails 3, [this blog post](http://www.andyhawthorne.net/2011/05/pagination-with-rails-3/) might prove useful.

If you need to paginate the XML output itself, regardless of the solution you choose, you will still have to break it into parts, so you will have some basis for breaking it into pages. In other words, deal with each row in your XML data as a distinct record, the same way a DB would deal with it, and paginate off of that.

Comment: How to use it with an XML feed ?  I have used it before with DB content

Comment: So, you want to take the table you've created from the example page you referenced, and paginate the table, is that correct?

Comment: I've updated my answer. One way or another you need to break your XML data into something like a "row" or database record - there's no way around that. A list of distinct table rows (from a database, or from XML data) is the basis for all pagination solutions, regardless of the data they handle.

Comment: Is your XML data broken into rows? If so, wrap eat row into individual objects, and then paginate based on the total number of "rows" in the XML data.

Comment: It is broken if Produtcs - There are some produtcs "rows"

Comment: Ok, so treat each Product in the XML as a "row" (the same way you would treat the objects individually when you've done DB work in the past), and paginate using the Products. Does that make sense?